# Is there a way to make a non-editable span?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I am using a content editable div as an editor for real-time collaboration purposes. I need to paint carets/cursors for each user on the client side. I am doing this by adding and removing a span on each event like keypress and click.

```
<span id="caret1" style="fontSize:18px color:red">|</span>
```

How can I make this span non-editable? So that when a user leaves his caret at a constant position and another user edits something in this same position, he can't delete this caret by backspace or select it and edit it as if it was text.

**EDIT:**

```
<span id="caret1" style="fontSize:18px color:red" contenteditable=false>|</span>
```

Doesn't let users write in the span at least but the users are still able to delete this span by backspace.

Comment: tried that, didn't work!

Comment: try a 1px left or right border

Comment: instead of a span? hmm.. I can try but if there's a way for this to work with spans it would be better since I have all functions implemented properly

Comment: Yes I am using my own implementation. I agree that using span is better. I thought there was an easy way by CSS and I just didn't find it!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things

1) Your source code isn't formatted right. Too many double quotes.

```
"fontSize:18px" color:red"
```

2) The other thing is I haven't seen contentEditable as a true style, i've seen in action working more like a pseudoclass (being referenced in CSS files) or attribute to html tags, not as a style itself.

```
<span id="caret1" contentEditable="true" style="">
```

3) If neither of those work, you could try a javascript/jquery approach where deleting or backspacing to a point where there'd be two cursors on top of each other. you could add both ID's to the same span.

```
`<span id="caret1 caret2" style="fontSize:18px" contenteditable:"false" color:"red">|</span> `
```

and when caret2 does something different, move out of caret1, and create a new  for caret2...

To do that, you could use a little scripting (and maybe use something like [rangyInputs](https://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/)), and identify if the selected text has another caret in it... and also use a bit of that .on('keypress') to do validation on delete/backspace...